# How to update a class's list or dictionary when variables change elsewhere?

Tags: python, oop

How do you update a self.dictionary or self.list that contains other self.variables after being changed outside?

For instance we have the following test class:

```
class Test():
   def __init__(self):
       self.some_number = 0
       self.other_number = 0
       self.lst=[self.some_number, self.other_number]
       self.dic={'some_number': self.some_number, 'other_number': self.other_number}

   def update_values(self):
       self.number = 2
       self.other_number = 3
```

Then updating the values:

```
test = Test()                  

print(test.dic)
print(test.lst)

test.update_values()

print(test.dic) 
print(test.lst)
```

results in no change:

```
{'other_number': 0, 'some_number': 0}
[0, 0]
{'other_number': 0, 'some_number': 0}
[0, 0]
```

I actually thought, that the dictionary and list hold the **reference** to these variables pointing somewhere in memory. So if these change, that should change as well. But this doesn't seem to be the case. Is there any explanation?

Comment: Why do you have the same values replicated through your class instance? That seems like a Bad Idea and Error Prone. If you just use a dict, you can get the names or values with dict.keys() or dict.values(). If order is important as with the list, use collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: no order is not important. the idea was to collect everything additionally inside one dic, e.g. for a later **pretty print** operation on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to reflect the updated values in what you get when using `self.lst` or `self.dic`, make them a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_number = 0
        self.other_number = 0

    def update_values(self):
        self.some_number = 2
        self.other_number = 3

    @property
    def lst(self):
        return [self.some_number, self.other_number]

    @property
    def dic(self):
        return {'some_number': self.some_number,
                'other_number': self.other_number}
```

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.lst
[0, 0]
>>> t.dic                                                          
{'some_number': 0, 'other_number': 0}
>>> t.update_values()
>>> t.lst                                                          
[2, 3]
>>> t.dic 
{'some_number': 2, 'other_number': 3}
```

Comment: Fair point; OTOH, that does invoke the overhead of a method call and dynamically rebuilding the list / dict _on every access_. That may be ok for tiny containers, but not if they have many elements.

Comment: @PM2Ring I fail to imagine a class with so many attributes that the cost of rebuilding the list or dict would become a problem...

Comment: If python dynamically rebuilds the list / dic, what happens to the old data? will python copy from memory to memory? or just reassign?

Comment: @xaratustra: The Ned Batchelder article I linked to should answer your questions. But in the meantime, I'll add some info to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, names are references. But when in `update_values` you do `self.number = whatever`, you are *rebinding* self.number to point to a different integer. `self.lst` still contains a reference to the original integer.

If integers were mutable, you could mutate the value of `self.number` and that would be reflected in `self.lst`. But they aren't, so you can't. If you used some other kind of object, that would be visible though. For example:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.first = [0]
    self.lst = [self.first]

def update_values(self):
    self.first[0] += 1
```

Here we are mutating self.first, not rebinding it, so self.lst will reflect the change.

Answer (score 2):

Integers are immutable, so that won't work. But you can achieve what you want using lists:

```
class Test(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.some_number = [0]
       self.other_number = [0]
       self.lst=[self.some_number, self.other_number]
       self.dic={'some_number': self.some_number, 
           'other_number': self.other_number}

   def update_values(self):
       self.some_number[0] = 2
       self.other_number[0] = 3


test = Test()

print(test.dic)
print(test.lst)

test.update_values()

print(test.dic) 
print(test.lst)
```

**output**

```
{'some_number': [0], 'other_number': [0]}
[[0], [0]]
{'some_number': [2], 'other_number': [3]}
[[2], [3]]
```

Note that we have to *mutate* the `some_number` and `other_number` lists, i.e., modify their contents. If we simply replace them with new lists, then we don't get the desired propagation:

```
#This doesn't do what we want because it replaces the old list
#objects with new ones.
def update_values(self):
    self.some_number = [2]
    self.other_number = [3]
```

---

The way Python name binding works can be a little bewildering at first, especially if you're coming from another language. IMO, it's best to try to understand this idiom in its own terms, rather than trying to understand it in terms of references, pointers, etc.

I suggest you take a look at [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder; that article's also available in video form on YouTube.

In a comment you ask:

> If python dynamically rebuilds the list / dic, what happens to the old
>   data? Will Python copy from memory to memory? Or just reassign?

A Python variable, whether it's a simple variable or an attribute like `self.some_number`, isn't a container that holds a value. It's a name that's been bound to an object. `a=0` creates an `int` object with a value of 0 and binds that object to the name `a` in the local scope. If you then do `a=2` an `int` object with a value of 2 is created and bound to `a`, and the previous 0 object is reclaimed.

(For efficiency, small integers in the range -5 and 256 (inclusive) are cached, integer objects outside that range are created when needed and destroyed when they're no longer needed, i.e., when there are no longer any names bound to them).

When you do

```
a = 1234
b = 5678
mylist = [a, b]
```

Two integer objects are created and bound to the names `a` and `b`. IOW, `a` is a name for the `1234` object, `b` is a name for the `5678` object. Sometimes this is described by saying that `a` holds a reference to the `1234` integer object. But IMO it's better (and simpler) to think of `a` as being a key in a dictionary, with the `1234` integer object as the associated value.

Then `mylist = [a, b]` makes `mylist[0]` an alternate name for the `1234` object, and `mylist[1]` an alternate name for the `5678` object. The `1234` and `5678` objects themselves aren't copied in memory. Essentially, a Python list is an array of pointers to the objects it holds (with some added machinery that makes the list a proper Python object).

In mkrieger1's code, a new list object is created every time you retrieve the `Test.lst` property; there's no "old list" unless you've saved it somewhere by binding it, somehow.

I hope that was helpful and not too confusing. :)

Comment: thanks I didn't know about this. I am going to check the article you sent. Only the fact that I had to take care of the numbers as lists made me finally go for the solution using @property as was suggested above, because the dic is relatively small.